# Message box when date pickker date selected

Tags: vba, datepicker

first post and fairly new to VBA so apologies in advance

I have insatlled a datepicker on a user form in vba and would like a message box to appear once a date has been seleted

I am currently using the code below under "change" however it then brings the meesage box up when you try and click through the months, and i would just like it to appear once the date has been selected

```
    Private Sub DTPicker1_Change()
    MsgBox "Is the date within the next 28 days?"
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which date picker? where did you get it from (*Additional controls? or external addin?*)

Comment: the add in to the vba userform toolbox its called microsift date and time picker control 6.0

Comment: assuming you using a 32bit office. Which version or year?

Comment: also maybe see [**THIS**](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class), look at the events and see if you can work out which one is responsible for what and how to obtain what the user has clicked

Comment: Sorry the link you provided does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_CloseUp()
    MsgBox "Is the date within the next 28 days?"
End Sub
```

That should be the proper event. Tested and was working for me.